# SVG databinding based on key

Tags: d3.js, svg, binding

I have an svg like below

```
<g>
   <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" id='path1'/>
   <path d="M151 0 L75 200 L225 100 Z" id='path2'/>
   <path d="M152 0 L75 200 L225 300 Z" id='path3'/>
   <path d="M153 0 L75 200 L225 400 Z" id='path4'/>
</g>
```

And I have a data.json like

```
{
    [
      "path2",
      "22218",
      "26627",
      "29101"
    ],
    [
      "path4",
      "218",
      "207",
      "160"
    ]
    [
      "path3",
      "22218",
      "26627",
      "29101"
    ],
    [
      "path1",
      "218",
      "207",
      "160"
    ]
}
```

I am confused as how to bind the data based on the key.I am assuming that I can use the first element in each array as the data-key. But how do I use it in the `.data()` function?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Providing a key function will have no effect on selections with no data bound.

Comment: Lars is correct, as usual. If your objective is to relate some json data to existing SVG elements and you can order said elements, you can sort your json to be in sync with the elements. Once done you can apply data from your json to the "associated" svg element after binding them. In this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PeLgP/1/) I derive the color of each path element from the common id between them and the json data. Anyways, this may be far afield of what you were looking for with data keying but I wanted to see what I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll want to assign 'dummy' data to the existing elements, based on some attribute of that element (in this case, the 'id' attribute) using [selection.datum](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#datum).  The data you assign should put the identifier in the same format you'll be using with your actual input data (in this case, index 0 of the array is the identifier):

```
var paths = d3.selectAll("path")
    .datum(function(d) { return [d3.select(this).attr("id")]; })
```

Then, you can assign data to these paths, and use a key function, as per usual:

```
    .data(data, function(d) { return d[0]; });
```

To test, you can print to the console:

```
paths.each(function(d) { console.log(this, d); });
```

which in this case, outputs:

```
<path id="path2" d="M151 0 L75 200 L225 100 Z"> ["path2", "22218", "26627","29101"]
<path id="path4" d="M153 0 L75 200 L225 400 Z"> ["path4", "218", "207", "160"]
<path id="path3" d="M152 0 L75 200 L225 300 Z"> ["path3", "22218", "26627", "29101"]
<path id="path1" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"> ["path1", "218", "207", "160"]
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c3tVm/1/).