# d3 data binding array of objects by id value to loaded svg

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, d3.js

I've looked through several potential answers to my particular conundrum and haven't found the perfect solution. [This exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990350/svg-databinding-based-on-key) came closest to the mark, in which Josh shows a simple way to use d3's .datum to temporarily bind an existing svg's id to it's **data**. Then, he uses the .data key function to update **data** based on the matching value in a simple array of arrays.

I'm trying to do something similar, but with an array of objects. But for some reason my key function won't find object value I'm looking for. If I use an array of arrays, like Josh, no problem. I thought I might need to use d3.values or d3.entries; but it doesn't look like the case.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

My svg has a bunch of g elements with state abbreviations for id attributes (e.g. ...The groups are filled with paths.

My data array looks like this:

```
var data = [
{

  "st" : "MI",
  "state" : "Michigan",
  "someValue" : 0.067
},
{
  "st" : "CA",
  "state" : "California",
  "someValue" : 0.111
},
etc.}];
```

My attempt to bind the data to my SVG g elements goes like this:

```
$("#map").load("mymap.svg", function() {
    var theMap = d3.selectAll("#map svg g")
      .datum(function(d) { return [d3.select(this).attr("id")]; })
      .data(data, function(d){ return d.st; });
    theMap.each(function(d) { console.log( this, d.state ); });
  });
```

I feel like I'm overlooking something very simple, but can't figure it out. Maybe I just need more coffee. If you have a minute to point out the error of my ways, most appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: I don't see the difference to be honest -- your data has exactly the same structure as in the question you've linked to.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if I understand the issue. Are you saying that this isn't working for?

Comment: Excuse the pauses in my response; I'm stuck babysitting my kids at the same time I'm trying to wrap this project up. What I'm seeing in the dev console is that the binding of the id attributes works just fine. But then the binding of the data to replace it isn't taking effect using the d.st value as a key. So, the console.log(this, d.state) produces undefined for the SVG g elements. If I do a .data overwrite of .datum method without the key function, it overwrites the data; but obviously with the default indexing. Long story short...the problem is definitely with the key function as written.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I got it now. You would need `return [{st: d3.select(this).attr("id")}];` for the initial data binding though, no?

Comment: Hmm...didn't seem to work. I made a jsfiddle to experiement. If you open the dev tools, you'll see that d.state is still undefined. http://jsfiddle.net/jlmyers42/gyc4hg59/

Comment: Yep, ignore the `[]` around the return value, just return the object: http://jsfiddle.net/gyc4hg59/5/

Comment: 1 million rep pts for you, Lars! Thanks; all fixed. I hope this is a useful question for others. I looked far and wide for something similar and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data is structured slightly differently to the question you've linked to, so you need to return a different structure in the initial data binding:

```
.datum(function(d) { return {st: d3.select(this).attr("id")}; })
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gyc4hg59/5/).

Comment: You get a bonus 1 million rep pts from me. Thanks so much!